# PorterStemmer with verbs ending in -es and -ed java

Tags: java, eclipse, nlp, porter-stemmer, jaws-wordnet

i am using PorterStemmer in java to get the base form of a verb, But i found a problem with the verbs "goes" and "gambles". Instead of stemming it to "go" and "gamble", it stems them to "goe" and "gambl". Is there a better tool that can handle verbs that ends with -es and -ed to retrieve the base form of a verb? P.S JAWS with wordnet java does that too.
Here is my code:

```
public class verb
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PorterStemmer ps = new PorterStemmer();
        ps.setCurrent("gambles");
        ps.stem();
        System.out.println(ps.getCurrent());        
    }
}
```

Here is the output in console: 
`gambl`

Comment: It is often taken to be a crude error that a stemming algorithm does not leave a real word after removing the stem. But the purpose of stemming is to bring variant forms of a word together, not to map a word onto its ‘paradigm’ form. Source - https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do.  From your question, it's hard to tell whether you want to use the PorterStemmer to do something or if you are logging an error against the PorterStemmer.  I think the direction that you are headed is to take the output of the PorterStemmer and correlate it to the root word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a few minutes to read this tutorial of Stanford NLP group

https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html

You can find the stemmer actually is not working as what you may think. It is crude so it not always gives you a complete base form of verbs with the ending chopped off. In your case, since you are caring about getting a complete base form of a verb, lemmatization seems better for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time i will check it out.